# How can I use raw_input to receive input from stdin in python 2.7?

Tags: python, python-2.7, stdin, raw-input

To receive input from stdin in python 2.7, I typically `import sys` and use `sys.stdin`. However, I have seen examples where `raw_input` is used to receive input from stdin, including multi-line input. How exactly can I use raw_input in place of sys.stdin? Here is an example problem:

input.txt:

```
Print
me
out
```

And I am running this command:

```
cat input.txt | python script.py
```

What can I put in script.py such that it will print out all lines of input using `raw_input`?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
while True:
    try:
        print raw_input()
    except EOFError:
        break
```

`raw_input` will only return single lines from stdin, and throws `EOFError` when EOF is read.

Comment: When will it throw an EOFError?

Comment: https://latedev.wordpress.com/2012/12/04/all-about-eof/

Comment: Why would this throw EOF?

Comment: Also, each `raw_input` receives just one line of stdin?

Comment: EOF is a way your operating system signifies that there is nothing more to be read from the reading source. `raw_input` is defined to keep returning lines from stdin until EOF is reached, and when it is reached it will throw a `EOFError`.

Comment: But after it reaches the end of stdin, won't `raw_input` then prompt for the user to enter new input?

Comment: @Rohan: It would prompt the input source to enter more input, but you’re piping the input in from a file. If it’s reached the end of the file, there’s really no way for it to ‘ask the file for more input’, so it throws an `EOFError`. (Similarly, even if standard input were not redirected, the user can press control-D or equivalent to send an EOF to a program, which will again cause an `EOFError` to be thrown.)